Can you determine if your grandmother was a child of incest with your DNA?
Is it possible to find out if your grandmother was a child of incest only having access to your DNA test?

If you are asking about a situation where one of your grandmother's parents was not her real parent, but it was instead a close relative of the other parent, then you likely can tell if you have enough relevant matches.
Your matches related to the incestual great grandparent would be 3rd cousins or 2C1R and will match like they should or closer depending on who the incest was with.
And your 3rd cousin matches and 2C1R related to your grandmother's other parent likely won't match you much if at all, since your grandmother's thought-to-be parents likely aren't closely related.
So if you have 3rd cousins or 2C1R in your match list that should be related to just one of your grandmother's parents, you should be able to tell if they were the true parents or not.
